# ImportError: No module named theano.sandbox using Jupyter notebook

Tags: theano, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to work with Keras on some small datasets locally, using my cpu.

I started a jupyter notebook, and selected what I think might be the right kernel, which would be the `conda env:tensorflow`:

[image]

So I try to import from the sandbox:

`from theano.sandbox import cuda` .

and I get

`ImportError: No module named theano.sandbox`

I don't get it. Theano is installed. Tensorflow is installed. Anaconda is installed. How can I figure out what is going on?